# How to recover a deleted screen recording that was recorded using Screen Recorder on a Mac?

Tags: macos, filesystem, screen-capture, quicktime, trash

I'm exploring the possibility of recovering deleted screen recordings that were created using the default system Screen recorder application on a Mac Monterey OS version 12.2.1.
Where will the temporary file be located if it is created anywhere at all if after finishing recording the video, instead of “done” user clicks the trash button.

One more time, the sequence of my actions that I performed:

1. Open Screen Recorder
2. Start recording...
3. Stop recording your screen
4. Open your video in the lower right corner
5. Click trash button

Where is the recorded video now? Is it possible to find the temporarily created video file somewhere in the temporary folders?